# How can I compile a beamer presentation with pauses in same page?

Tags: beamer, compiling, presentations, pause

I want to compile my presentation, but as I have the pauses codes, 
\begin{itemize}
\item <1- | alert@1>
\item <2- | alert@2>
\end{itemize}
I wanted to do it in the same page.
I was looking for a way to compile it and I found this solution:
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
But after doing it, I lost all my pause in the presentation. 
So, there is any way to compile the presentation page in one page and still have a pause mode?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a pdf with a single page such that in presentation mode shows two items in sequence one another other (not both together)?

Comment: @ Sigur this is that I want.

Comment: @Gilson See the edit to my answer. If that is indeed what you want, that's straightforward. But do note that it depends on having one page per item in the output PDF in order to render the changes to the slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way to do that. At least, there is no way to do that with `beamer` or any TeX software I'm aware of. The pauses just *are* separate pages in the output PDF. When you display the slides, a pause corresponds to a change from one page of the PDF to the next. So, if you have *n* pauses on a slide, you need *n+1* pages in the PDF. Remove the page breaks and you remove the pauses. These are not distinct things. That is just how the pauses are implemented in the PDF.

## EDIT

If you in fact want what Sigur described - that is, the first item on the first slide only, the second on the second slide only and so on - that is straightforward:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{A Title}
    \begin{itemize}[<+| alert@+>]
        \item This item appears only on the first slide.
        \item This item appears only on the second slide.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This puts the first item only on the first slide and the second item only on the second slide. However, it does this by using two pages in the output PDF:

[image: Item per slide]

Comment: This is not I want. but as you said, may it is not possible.

Comment: @Gilson If you want a pause with only 1 page in the PDF, that is impossible. Pauses just are new pages in the PDFs `beamer` creates. When you show the slides, you are turning the pages of the PDF. So the number of pages must always be one greater than the number of transitions (new slides + pauses within slides) in your presentation.